# XML & XPath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

Say I have this XML:

```
<root>
    <A></A>
    <B></B>
    <C>one</C>
    <C>two</C>
    <C>three</C>
    <D></D>
</root>
```

Now I want to get all nodes, except for The C nodes 'two' and 'three'.
Now I want to choose which C node can stay by index.

So this is the xpath that I already have:

```
 //*[not(ancestor-or-self::C)]
```

But this removes all C nodes, so now I have to add an index to which C node I want to stay

```
//*[not(ancestor-or-self::C)] exept for C[1]
```

How can I accomplsh this so my output would be if I select index 1:

```
<root>
   <A></A>
   <B></B>
   <C>one</C>
   <D></D>
</root>
```

Or if I select index 2:

```
<root>
   <A></A>
   <B></B>
   <C>two</C>
   <D></D>
</root>
```

Hope I made myself clear enough :p
thx

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why except? You have *any element but those*, then you **add** some of those:

```
//*[not(ancestor-or-self::C)]|//C[1]/descendant-or-self::*
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it depends on what you define as "index". If you define "index" as the C that has n-1 C siblings then you can just do:

to display one the first (get rid of all afterwards

```
/root/*[not(name() = 'C'  and count(preceding::C) >= 1)]
```

to display only the second

```
/root/*[not(name() = 'C' and (count(preceding::C) < 1 or count(preceding::C) > 1))]
```

(I tested this with: http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx just fyi )

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//*[not(self::c and not(count(preceding-sibling::c) = $ind - 1))]
```

where $ind is the wanted position (1-based) of the `c` element you want to select.